# How to compare float and decimal in python?

Tags: python, decimal, precision, floating-accuracy

I have a (`decimal.Decimal`) column in a dataframe as below:

```
    dt = pd.DataFrame({"OPEN": [-0.00010,-0.0114, 0.0066,-0.0044,-0.0012,-0.0005,
                                 0.0005,-0.0037, -0.0029, 0.0034, 0.0003, 0.0001 ]})

dt["OPEN"] = dt["OPEN"].apply(Decimal)
```

and I would like to `apply` the following method over the `Open` column:

```
def label_change_price(delta):

    if 0 < abs(delta) < 0.0001:
        print(" Return value: ",0, "Delta: ",delta)
        return 0
    elif 0.0001 <= abs(delta) < 0.0002:
        print(" Return value: ",1, "Delta: ",delta)
        return int(np.sign(delta)) * 1
    elif 0.0002 <= abs(delta) < 0.0003:
        print(" Return value: ",2, "Delta: ",delta)
        return int(np.sign(delta)) * 2
    elif 0.0003 <= abs(delta):
        print(" Return value: ",3, "Delta: ",delta)
        return int(np.sign(delta)) * 3
```

When i run the code, for the very first row (`-0.00010`) it print

`Return value:  0 Delta:  -0.00010`

which is wrong, as it must return `1`, however it returns `0`.

In other word, the first condition in `if` comes `True` and it does not continue to the second `elif`.

So, I am wondering, why my second `elif 0.0001 <= abs(delta) < 0.0002:` is not working well, when the delta is 0.0001 ? And how i can fix it ?

Comment: can not reproduce with `delta = -0.0001` followed by `print(0.0001 <= abs(delta) < 0.0002)` I get True ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. Jeff can you please edit this into a complete standalone program so that others can more easily test whether this can be reproduced.

Comment: hmm, i read my real dataset from a `csv` file. could it be the reason of the problem ?

Comment: Possibly, but please show a minimal CSV file that exhibits the problem and the actual code used to read and process it. The more easily people can reproduce the problem, the more chance that you will get an answer.

Comment: If your `delta` value was EVER a float, then is *physically impossible* for it to have the exact value -0.0001 - no such value even exists in the usual binary floating-point representation.  It's actually something like -0.000100000000000000005.  To get accurate Decimal values (and what's the point, otherwise?), you have to convert directly from a string representation.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, delta comes from the `dt["OPEN"]` which used to be a `float` value and i applied `Decimal` to it.

Answer (score -1):

You might try comparisons like this:

```
if abs(Decimal(0)) < abs(delta) < abs(Decimal(0.0001)):
```

Comparisons seem tricksy:

```
from decimal import Decimal

Decimal(0.0001) == 0.0001
# True

abs(Decimal(0.0001)) == 0.0001
# False

Decimal(0.0001) == Decimal(0.0001)
# True

abs(Decimal(0.0001)) == Decimal(0.0001)
# False

abs(Decimal(0.0001)) == abs(Decimal(0.0001))
# True
```

Comment: Yes, but why is it so complex ?